Bound from below for Polynomial Matrix
Let $x\in\mathbb R$ and consider the polynomial matrix $P(x)\in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. In other words, $P(x)$ is a matrix with polynomial entries:
$$
P(x) = P_0 + P_1 x + \ldots + P_d x^d,
$$
where $P_i$ are $n \times n$ matrices.
Assume that $P(x)$ is invertible for every $x$ large enough. I want to know if it is true that there exists $C > 0$ independent of $x$ such that
$$
\min_{V \in \mathbb R^n, \|V\|=1} \|P(x)V\| \geq C,
$$
for every $x$ large enough.
I feel like this should be true since $P(x)$ is invertible, but I do not know how to prove it (or disprove it, as I haven't found counterexamples yet). Note that the statement is equivalent to say that
$$
\|P^{-1}(x)\| \leq \frac{1}{C},
$$
for every $x$ large enough, which is stronger, for instance, than what is proved here .

One counterexample is $P(x)=\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Its two singular values satisfy $\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2=\|P(x)\|_F^2=x^2+2$ and $\sigma_1\sigma_2=|\det P(x)|=1$. Thus, $\sigma_2\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, so $\min_{\|V\|=1}\|P(x)V\|=\sigma_2$ also tends to zero.

Thank you, this actually works and disproves my statement! I guess one cannot do better than the polynomial decay described in the link I provided (and indeed $\sigma_2 \sim x^{-2}$ in your example.
